# Ampere's force and Superconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

It is well known that there will be [Ampere's force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law) if we put wire with current to external magnetic field.

But what about superconductors? Is there any Ampere's force for it or because of [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect) there will be no any force?

Comment: [Magnetic fields certainly can exert forces on superconductors](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=superconductor+levitation&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB703GB703&biw=1920&bih=950&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu7Nuv86rQAhUEDcAKHc7YC4cQ_AUICCgD)

Comment: I do not mean levitation. It is different. I mean Amper's force which depends on current value inside wire and which can be changed by changing current or external field.